# Implementation of a Negative binomial with two overdispersion parameter through IWLS

Tags: r

### Theory

Inspired from [Lindén and Mäntyniemi](https://esajournals.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1890/10-1831.1)'s paper to use two overdispersion parameters to model the linear and! the quadratic mean-variance relationship. See the following equation. The case theta = 0 corresponds to a quasi-poisson, the case omega = 1 to the regular negative binomial.

sigma^2 = omega * mu + theta * mu^2

I mostly followed [Ver Hoef and Boveng](https://digitalcommons.unl.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1141&context=usdeptcommercepub) to implement it through iterative weighted least squares (IWLS).

### Implementation IWLS

I can test the following code for the quasi-poisson and a negative binomial with omega fixed to one, but can not verify that it is well implemented for the negative binomial with omega unequal 1.

```
IWLS <- function(Omega1,Theta1,tollvl=1,X=X){
X <- as.matrix(X) # model.matrix(), factor variables only
mu <- rep(mean(Y),length(X[,1]))
Omega <- Omega1
Theta <- Theta1
Y.head<-Y # 152 datapoints
tol=10
i=1

while(tol>tollvl){ # Iterative
W<-diag(c(mu/(Omega[i] + Theta[i]*mu)) ) 
# Theta = 0 -> Quasipoisson, Omega = 1 -> negbin, both unfixed (reason wrote this code)
Beta.head<-solve(t(X)%*%W%*%X,t(X), tol=9^-45)%*%W%*%Y.head
nu <- X%*%Beta.head
mu <- exp(nu)
Y.head <- nu + (Y-mu)/mu # derivative of log(nu) -> 1/nu
if(Theta1==0){
    Theta <- c(Theta,0)
    Omega <- c(Omega,mean( (Y-mu)^2/mu) )
} else{ 
    if(Omega1==1){
    Theta<- c(Theta,mean( (( (Y-mu)^2) - mu )/mean(mu)^2))  
    Omega <- c(Omega,1)
    } else{ # NB2
    ThetaF  <- mean( (Y-mu)^2 - mu )/(mean(mu)^2) 
    Omega <- c(Omega,mean( ((Y-mu)^2)/mu - mu*ThetaF) )
    Theta  <- c(Theta,mean( ((Y-mu)^2 - mu*Omega[i+1] )/(mean(mu)^2 )) )
    }
}
tol <- abs(Omega[i+1]-Omega[i])+abs(Theta[i+1]-Theta[i])
i <- i+1
}
list(Omega=Omega,
     Theta=Theta,
     Beta.head=Beta.head,
     SE = sqrt(diag(solve(t(X)%*%W%*%X))),
     FittedValues = mu)
}
```

### Questions / Problems

The main concern is about the following line, specifiing the double overdispersed negative binomial. I found no literature to back up that code. I tried a for() loop here and different approaches regarding the mean, since taking the mean for every mu or taking the mean at the end highly influences the result.

```
else{ # NB2
    ThetaF  <- mean( (Y-mu)^2 - mu )/(mean(mu)^2) 
    Omega <- c(Omega,mean( ((Y-mu)^2)/mu - mu*ThetaF) )
    Theta  <- c(Theta,mean( ((Y-mu)^2 - mu*Omega[i+1] )/(mean(mu)^2 )) )
    }
```

This version of the code works well (Beta.head same, only different SE compared to other two models) for a relatively small amount of covariates, where the model matrix has dimension of around 152:5. For more columns / multiple factor variables the algorithm fails to compute a standard error for every attribute with the **{In sqrt(diag(solve(t(X) %*% W %*% X))) : NaNs produced}**, indicating multilinearity. Theta and omega sometimes don't converge, but even if they do this message appears for more than one variable.

Testcode to run:

```
set.seed(123)
Y.Test<-sample(1:100,152,replace = T)*rpois(152,1)+1 # Try to model true data
XXX<-model.matrix(Y.Test~as.factor(sample(1:4,152,replace = T))+as.factor(sample(1:3,152,replace = T)))
Neg.Bin2.Test<-IWLS(Omega1 =var(Y)/mean(Y),Theta1 = var(Y)/mean(Y)^2 - 1/mean(Y), tollvl =  10^-10,X=XXX)
```

If multilinearity is the concern, why is it then only problematic for the double overdispersed model. A omega=1 fix solves the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. There were multiple issues.

Forgot the tolerance level in the list output, hence:

```
SE = sqrt(diag(solve(t(X)%*%W%*%X, tol=9^-45)))
```

Further were there issues with the computation of theta

Remove one mean(mu)

```
else{ 
    if(Omega1==1){ # Negative binomial Case
    Theta<- c(Theta,mean( ((Y-mu)^2 - mu )/mu^2 ) ) # no mean(mu)
    Omega <- c(Omega,1) 
    }
```

Here I had to add an additional step

```
else{ # Negative binomial with 2 overdispersion parameters
    OmegaF <- mean( ((Y-mu)^2)/mu )
    ThetaF  <- mean( ((Y-mu)^2 - mu )/mu^2 ) 
    Omega <- c(Omega,mean( ((Y-mu)^2)/mu - mu*ThetaF) )
    Theta  <- c(Theta,mean( ((Y-mu)^2 - mu*Omega[i+1] )/mu^2 )) 
    }
}
```